# Is it difficult to do a post-break-in wheel tune-up?

Tags: wheel-truing

I've heard that when you get new wheels you should put a couple hundred miles on them to let everything get set in and get an initial stretch, then do a tune up.

Can I just go by feel and tighten the spokes that seem a litte lose?  I don't think the wheels are untrue, they're heavy duty wheels.  Are there any tricks to this initial tune up?

Comment: Take it somewhere where it will be done right.  The store where you bought the bike should provide a free first checkup which would hopefully include a quick once-over on the wheels.

Comment: It's more than just tightening the ones that feel loose. Making an adjustment like that can have a ripple effect on both roundness and true of the wheel.

Comment: Thanks.  The wheels were bought from Nashbar, the nearby LBSs didn't have anything like them in the price range.  I'll pay the LBS to tune them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you should take it to a shop. You're likely to do more harm than good if you're not already experienced in at least truing and preferably building wheels.

It also might not even take a couple hundred miles. I'd probably check on it once a week or even every couple days. Feel the spokes. Once it gets to a point where there are notable differences in tension, go ahead and take it in.

Answer (score 3):

Don't cut corners or your new wheels won't last as long as they could, or worse, they might not last at all.

There are entire books written on truing bicycle wheels. Before you attempt to maintain your wheels yourself, without the shop, read those books, buy a good truing stand, and even then, practice on wheels you don't care about. There is an art to it.